# A letter is displayed after body tag in Prestashop website

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I have a prestashop website http://www.myparaweb.com/ which displays a 'l' letter after body tag, it's returned also in the ajax json response after back office loging so that the login is never succeed.
I tried to view the theme header.tpl, and the admin header.tpl and i didn't found it there

Attached the code screenshot and the json return with the 'l' in the beginning.
I'd like to remove this 'l' letter.
Thanks[image][image]

Edit: As i begin to found where the 'l' letter occurs, i debugged the __constructor function in the Dispatcher class

```
protected function __construct()
{   die("test");
    $this->use_routes = (bool)Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS');
...
}
```

This returned the 'l' letter like this

```
<html><head></head><body>ltest</body></html>
```

Edit2: i tried to debug into the getInstance function like this

```
public static function getInstance()
{   die('test');
    if (!self::$instance) {
        self::$instance = new Dispatcher();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

I got

```
<html><head></head><body>ltest</body></html>
```

Comment: If you're searching, that's a number 1.

Comment: Show the PHP. Generated source code doesn't help with PHP. Also screenshots are of little, most users aren't going to transcribe.

Comment: I didn't have a specific php source code, who knows prestashop know what i'm talking about, i will remove thee php tag

Comment: as @chris85 said, we'll need to see what is directly after your `<body>` tag in the php - Just looked at your site and it's an L, but your screenshot looks like a `1`

Comment: That's a `l` not a `1`.

Comment: I don't know why meta tags are loaded in the body tag, as in header.tp they are in the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at the source code the `l` character appears before your `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` declaration.

```html
l<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="fr-fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Default Ciblo theme</title>
```

As it appears on every page we are sure it's not a Controller but it might be the `/classes/controller/FrontController.php` classe.

If I were you, I would debug by printing `die("test")` at different steps in Prestashop process to find where this character comes from. By starting with the `FrontController` :

```php
class FrontControllerCore extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        die("test");
        [...]
    }
}
```

Then try with the `init()` function... Then `initContent()` and finally `displayHeader`.

This might be a long process taking you 1 hour or more of debug but you'll be sure to find the exact place of this bug.

---

**EDIT:** From your bellow comment, we can tell that this bug happens before the controller is called.

We will then start to debug from the `/index.php`:

```php
<?php
/**
[...]
*/
die("test");
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
```

Then:

```php
<?php
/**
[...]
*/
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
die("test");
Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch();
```

With this you will know if the bug happens before the dispatcher of after. If it happens in the config file, repeat the process in this file for each line to find which include causes this problem.

---

**EDIT:** From your comment bellow, the problem happens after the Dispatcher call so you'll have to dig into `/classes/Dispatcher.php`. Start by debuging the `__cunstructor()` function and then `dispatch()` function.

Comment: When testing your solution in __construct function, i get <html><head></head><body>ltest</body></html>

Comment: Ok so this happens before the controller is called. I'll edit my answer with other places to search.

Comment: It's not happened before or after the config.inc.php file, it happened after the dispatcher

Comment: Ok don't worry we're close to the solution ;). I've edited my answer, you will have to debug the Dispatcher.

Comment: When i debug the __constructor function it returned 
<html><head></head><body>ltest</body></html>

Comment: Was launch time here, let's continue.
So you don't have a `l` before calling the dispatcher but inside its constructor the `l` appears?

Comment: Have you look at the beginning of the Dispatcher file, is there something written before `<?php`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116804/discussion-between-tarek-fellah-and-florian-lemaitre).

Comment: Yes in the constructor it appears
No i haven't an 'l' before <?php in Dispatcher.php

Comment: I fixed the problem, it was in setting.inc.php, there was a cache issue when triying to debug thank you @Florian Lemaitre

Comment: You're welcome, could you please accept this answer if it helped you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try searching through all the framework files you edited. Its probably in one of them. 
An insane way to find out is to search for " 1 " in all php files. I used notepad++ to open about all *.php files in folders i edited to search for "1". Since the propability of having a "1" in you code is limited, you can easily find it. Go to each subfolder , search for "*.php" and open all files in notepad++, search for "1" in all open documents. Saves time rather than going through all code.